# Magento2 add a cms page link to menu

Tags: magento2, magento2.2, magento2.2.4, topmenu

I have added CMS page link to the top menu by following the below tutorial:

http://www.amitbera.com/magento2-add-a-cms-page-link-to-menu/

Since one of the custom menu items would be **Home**, so it should be the first item in the menu.

I want to know that how can I make some custom menu item as the first item in the top menu using the code in the tutorial.

**Update:** *Suppose, I have 2 custom menu items, say **`Home`** and **`Contact`**. I want to make Home as the first menu item and Contact as the last menu item. Is it possible with a single plugin class? or I have to write 2 different plugins to achieve this goal?*

Please help.

Comment: Need to change position of menu?

Comment: yes, I need to set the first position for the **`Home`** menu item.

Comment: With same way or any other way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a issue with plugin order

In default Magento already plugin define in `vendor/magento/module-catalog/etc/di.xml`

```
<type name="Magento\Theme\Block\Html\Topmenu">
    <plugin name="catalogTopmenu" type="Magento\Catalog\Plugin\Block\Topmenu" />
</type>
```

And we created custom plugin in **app\code{VendorName}{ModuleName}\etc\di.xml**

```
<type name="Magento\Theme\Block\Html\Topmenu">
    <plugin name="add_cms_menu" type="{VendorName}{ModuleName}\Plugin\Topmenu" sortOrder="0" />
</type>
```

That means core and custom plugin, both are same exist with same sort order.

If you want to display custom menu just before category menu, sort order required minimum values to core value.

Use below code for plugin and check you custom menu

```
<type name="Magento\Theme\Block\Html\Topmenu">
    <plugin name="add_cms_menu" type="{VendorName}{ModuleName}\Plugin\Topmenu" sortOrder="-1" />
</type>
```

I hope it will be useful for you. Let me know if not working

Comment: Great. I did not think about this. One more question. I want to add **`Home`** at the first place and **`Contact Me`** at the last place. Is it possible with a single plugin?

Comment: If not, I will still upvote your answer.

Comment: Accept my answer if resolve current asked issue.

Comment: I have upvoted and accepted.Now can you answer on my question which I asked in the comment?

Comment: I have updated my question now.

Comment: Accept my answer and ask separate question.

Comment: Sorry, but for a simple hint, it is not a wise choice to ask a different question when the next question is directly related to this one.

Comment: You have 2 choice to achieve this task, create two plugin with different sort order and second is without plugin you can achieve this task.

Comment: without plugin? How?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/80645/discussion-between-mohit-kumar-arora-and-suresh-chikani).